# Wso2 APIM is not showing logs of jar in carbon logs

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am using wso2 apim version 4.0.0, I have a jar from which i am calling mediation sequence in my api's to work, on publisher portal runtime tab in messageMediation, I am using System.out.println on various location in my code like System.out.println("Request Packet -> "+requestPacket.toString()) for printing them in carbon logs of wso2 apim but it is not printing in logs. on other hand, the log mediator i am using in mediation is working fine.

how can i make it possible to print jars logs in wso2 apim carbon logs. I do not want to user logfactory instead of this. Because these logs are printing before some time ago. do not know what causing this now.

Comment: A prompt response will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println` channels the logs to the STDOUT, so you will not see these logs in the `wso2carbon.log` file. But if you start the server in the foreground you should see these logs in your terminal. To get the logs in log files use proper log4j logging instead of using `System.out.println`.

Comment: can you please explain the solution? did not get it.